# Making model and setting values in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am working on an angular application. I want to send data to post API. My json looks something like this

```json
{
    "name": "julie",
    "id": 1,
    "PersonalDetails": {
        "homeId": 23,
        "homeName": "Julie Home"
    },
    "OfficialDetails": {
        "OfficeId": 45,
        "OfficeAddress": "Near townhall"
    }
}
```

In my component I want to make this data obviously will be setting values using variable in my component and send it to my post API method. In future I may need to send more model attaching in above structure but different data, so thinking if making interface will work. But I am new to typescript so not able to decide and do it

I just want to know what will be the good approach to make model for this and set values. How to make model/interface and set values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to make the basic interface for your data.

For example.

```
interface YourData {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  PersonalDetails?: PersonalDetails
  OfficialDetails?: OfficialDetails
}
```

Then, its better to create an interface for each subitem in your data. In your case its, `PersonalDetails` and `OfficialDetails`.

```
interface PersonalDetails {
  homeId?: number;
  homeName?: string;
}

interface OfficialDetails {
  OfficeId?: number;
  OfficeAddress?: string;
}
```

In future you can extend your interface and make you data flexible.

After successfully-created interface, just cast all values that you need, using the interface. For example:

```
sendData(payload: YourData): Observable<YourData> {
  return this.http.post<YourData>(payload)
    .pipe(
      ...
    );
}
```

Comment: almost all the things will come from UI. Like name. User will type name and as of now I am storing it in variable. How can I set name and other things? I thought I need to make object using new operator in component and set values Not sure though

Comment: Let me attach a useful tutorial for you https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-2-forms-reactive

This approach describe how you can implement the form on your UI, for example for your name value and others. Then, when you get the value from your form, you can cast your value with your interface. In current case, you don't need to use a `new` operator.
@Julie

Comment: I read your link but I am failing to understand one thing in your solution.How I can make my final data as I shown in my question so that I send pass it as a argument to my post method. ?

Comment: I want to make that structure in my component itself and after that I will just call my post method and will pass that model object to it. So How I can create a structure like I posted  in my question by using your solution?

Comment: Do I need to all these three interface in one file? or need to keep them in separate file?

Comment: You can keep all these interfaces in one file, but if your application will grow, its better to store them in separate files. The approach of splitting interfaces is good, because you can easily manage your data.

You can declare your object in the component like this:

```
dataObj: YourData = {
 id: 1,
  name: 'name',
 ....
}
```

Comment: dataObj: YourData = { id: 1, name: 'name', .... } in this I fI do  dataObj: YourData = { id: 1, name: 'name', PersonalDetails .homeId}, it is giving me error saying PersonDetails only refers to a type, but being used as value here" . How to assign these types of values?

Comment: You don't need to use interface in your object. The interface will be applied for all sub-properties, just cast it in the top of the object.

Comment: could you please give an example by editing your code above?

Comment: Sure, I have created [an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-tg7e2d?devtoolsheight=33&file=app/app.component.ts) for you. Hope its clear why and where we need to use the interface.